# Async ZeroMQ for nim

Tags: asynchronous, zeromq, nim-lang

I have never used ZeroMQ and first heard of it an hour ago. But from the guide ([this guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all)) it sounds like there are async I/O.

It also happens that there is a nim port : [this one](https://github.com/nim-lang/nim-zmq/blob/master/zmq.nim)

So I was wondering, does the async magic has something to do with `async`/`await` which are keywords not present in the nim port (which is just c2nim). So is it just something that's internal to ZMQ and the API doesn't have to bother about it ?

I thought async/await was a vernacular thing that has to bubble up to the upper most main loop (framework loop) so the API would have to be async-aware.

Is this a complete misconception on my part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Native ZeroMQ API supports both blocking and non-blocking I/O-s.

For this purpose, there are **`flags`**, where **`zmq.NOBLOCK`** could be added, so as to achieve a non-blocking mode of operation.

---

### The respective language-wrapper functionality decides . . .

If I read the [nim](/questions/tagged/nim)  [ZeroMQ-wrapper](https://github.com/nim-lang/nim-zmq/blob/master/zmq.nim), that you have mentioned above, it seems to me, that there is a hardcoded blocking version for both `send()` and `recv()` function-wrappers.

The wrapper also seems not to support correct wireline message sizing in case  a [nim](/questions/tagged/nim)-based node of a [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) meets another node, which is using ZeroMQ version 2.1.+, which is still interesting and common in heterogeneous [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) realms.

ZeroMQ has also a `poll()` method, equipped with a `timeout` parameter, so that your multiplexed I/O-operations may yield all wanted ways of how to operate multiple I/O-channels under some soft real-time control constraints.

Comment: Maybe using ZMQ's async API would require to make sure that the buffers are pinned (because nim is garbage collected), which makes it non trivial ? no idea.

Comment: After more than a decade with ZeroMQ, I would guess, there is no easy re-engineering of the `Context()`-instance memory-management under way in any near future as there have been spent a lot of performance-tweaking `[man*years]` of elite design and engineering efforts ( and imported DLL components IMHO have nothing to do with port-targeted ecosystem ( nim ) garbage collector or other features, that live "in front" of the API mediated DLL-ed subsystem ). So if nim-port delivers un-distorted API service, yet it cannot but re-use the external, DLL-imported functionality. If not, none feature will

Comment: From what I can tell, and I am by no means an zmq expert (but I did write the async await in Nim), you need to integrate zmq with Nim's event loop somehow. The aforementioned `poll` sounds like a good start, although there are quite a few challenges along the way. Feel free to get in touch with me on IRC if you'd like some help getting it working :)

Comment: @v.oddou greetings to Tokyo, guess you shall not miss Dominik's offer above this comment.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer was true at the time; async with ZMQ now is built with the wrapper and there are examples provided :

See :

- https://github.com/nim-lang/nim-zmq/blob/master/zmq/asynczmq.nim
- https://github.com/nim-lang/nim-zmq/blob/master/examples/ex08_async_reqrep.nim

You can also work around the blocking behaviour or ZMQ in order to not block the async-dispatch loop manually with poll / sleepAsync :

```
let
  zmq_timeout = 50
  async_loop_time = 450 # spend more time on async stuff than on zmq stuff
var
  conn = listen("tcp://127.0.0.1:36000", mode = PAIR=
  poller = initZPoll([conn], ZMQ_POLLIN)

if poller.poll(timeout):
  if events(poller[0]):
    var res = poller[0].receive()
    # Do async stuff
else:
  waitFor sleepAsync(async_loop_time) # Calling sleepAsync is a trick to make the async dispatch loop progress for a time
```